# How can I find max value in SQL and read into PHP using PDO?

Tags: php, sql

I am using PHP to create a website whereby a user inputs values into a new row on one page (values for Awinner, Arunner and so on) and on the next page those values are retrieved from the database. For this to work I need to find the most recent id which will always be the highest. What code can I put in between the hashtags below in order to do this?

```
$sql  = "SELECT Awinner, Arunner, Bwinner, Brunner, Cwinner, Crunner, Dwinner, Drunner FROM groupStage";
$sql .= " WHERE id = #the maximum id#";
```

Then after this, I need to put each value (Awinner, Arunner, Bwinner, etc.) into its own variable in PHP so that I can display them all separately on the page. How can I do this? Sorry for lack of detail here but I am a newbie to PHP and SQL and am working on an important school project.

Comment: I may be wrong but suspect this is the wrong question. It sounds like you have records inserted, they get an id, and you want those same records from another page. You *assume* that these will be those with the highest ID, but what if two people are inserting records and they overlap? Basically it's an unsafe assumption, if not today, at some point. When you insert you can query what ID was assigned, and what you should then do is propagate *that* ID to the next page and query records for the ID passed to that page. This might be a GET or POST param or a session variable. HTH and good luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try like below by using subquery

```
"SELECT Awinner, Arunner, Bwinner, Brunner, Cwinner, Crunner, Dwinner, Drunner FROM groupStage where id= ( select max(id) from groupStage)"
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't use a `where` use an `order by` with a `limit` to only return the 1 row.

```
SELECT Awinner, Arunner, Bwinner, Brunner, Cwinner, Crunner, Dwinner, Drunner
FROM groupStage
order by `the maximum id` desc
limit 1
```